# Resolving generic method parameters in C#

Tags: c#, wsdl

I have a method that is overloaded 3 times with the exact same functionality, the only change is one parameter which is a list of a concrete type.

```
private void _doWork(string name, List<TargetItem> members)
{
    foreach(var member in members)
    {
      _doExtraWork(member.TimeToWork);
    }
}

private void _doWork(string name, List<NonTargetItem> members)
{
    foreach(var member in members)
    {
      _doExtraWork(member.TimeToWork);
    }
}
```

Thing to know here is the 2 classes in the lists are coming from a WSDL definition. The operation in the iteration is on shared members as they derive from the same base class, however this inheritance is abstracted in the WSDL.

I have tried to do something like this -

```
private void _doWork<T>(string name, List<T> members)
{
    var commonList = new List<>(); /// what type should I use here?

    if(typeof (T) == typeof(TargetItem))
    {
      commonList = members; // assume equal to means copying members to commonList with type conversion
    }
    if(typeof (T) == typeof(NonTargetItem))
    {
      commonList = members;
    }
    foreach(var member in commonList)
    {
      _doExtraWork(member.TimeToWork);
    }
}
```

Is this the right way to approach the problem and refactor this common code, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Wont be better to do TargetItem and NonTargetItem inherit a common base which implements the shared parts (TimeToWork) and in this way you can manipulate it as the base objects?

Comment: I have stated this in the question they do inherit ffrom a common base but their definition is in a WSDL

Comment: Ouch, sorry, that's the problem reading just the code :D

Comment: tunnel vision is reality ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose to downcast from the caller

```
_doWork("Target", Object.TargetItems.ToList<BaseClass>());
_doWork("NonTarget", Object.NonTargetItems.ToList<BaseClass>());
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
 private static void _doWork<T>(string name, T members) where T : IEnumerable
{
     foreach(var member in members)
    {
      _doExtraWork(member.TimeToWork);
    }
}
```

In your Calling Code

```
_doWork("sdfsd", new List<TargetItem>()); // here just as example I am passing new instance
_doWork("sdfsd", new List<NonTargetItem>()); // here just as example I am passing new instance
```

As the `List<T>` is of type `IEnumerable<T>` which in turn is of type IEnumerable. You can add IEnumerable generic constaints in your generic functions. In this way, you do not have to do type checking in your generic functions.

If you want to implement single doExtraWork method then you need to have CommonType for both TargetItem and NonTargetItem. you can solve this using Adapter Pattern like below

```
Interface IItem
{
 int TimeToWorkAdapt {get;}
}

//Now create a wrapper class for TargetItem and NonTargetItem

Class TargetItemAdapt : TargetItem,IItem
{
   public int TimeToWorkAdapt 
       {
           get { base.TimeToWork;}    
       }
}

Class NonTargetItemAdapt : NonTargetItem,IItem
{
   public int TimeToWorkAdapt 
       {
           get { base.TimeToWork;}    
       }
}
 // write a generic function which wrap calls to your do extra work method but with generic constriants to interface
private static void _doExtraWork<T>(T members) where T : IItem
    {
          _doExtraWork(member.TimeToWorkAdapt);

    }
// In your Main program...now use our wrapper classes

_doWork("sdfsd", new List<TargetItemAdapt>()); // here just as example I am passing new instance
_doWork("sdfsd", new List<NonTargetItemAdapt>()); // here just as example I am passing new instance
```

Comment: Thanks Viru, good idea - it leads to a compiler error saying it cannot resolve TimeToWork, and it is expected, since we are not resolving T.

Comment: What if you pass member instead of passing member.TimeToWork? I think you will need two _doExtraWork. one with TargetItem as parameter and another one as NonTargetItem.

Comment: If you want to still use one method then you have to implement adapter pattern as there is no base class between these two. I ll post a example in a min

Comment: thing is - TimeToWork is a number and _doExtraWork takes an int, and prints the value to a text file, and if I try to make _doExtraWork take in an object, then I will have to overload _doExtraWork, and we end up with the same problem :)

Comment: @lolcat I think this should solve your problem...let me how it works out

Comment: yes, however, I was working off of your solution and this is dangerous but works -    `foreach(dynamic member in members)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104571/discussion-between-lolcat-and-viru).